# Uninstall git language on macos

Tags: macos, git, homebrew

The last brew update installed language support for my local language, so now git is a horribly bad almost unusable translation, and I want the english version back again.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may add `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` to your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` file,
or add `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` or just `LC_ALL=C` before your command.

You may also sabotage the git language support files - if git does not find files
for your language it will default to English.